# Garbage collection in .net

Tags: .net, garbage-collection, double

A Line class have reference to two objects of Point class (as start_Point and end_Point).
Consider the scenario where :
Line l1 and l2 share some point (say l1.end_Point = l2.start_Point).

Now if the l1 has gone out of scope(no more references to object of l1) but l2 is still referenced,
will the object of l1 be garbage collected if yes then what will happen to objects of points that were being held by l1.

---

There is no path from GCRoot to l1.start_Point but for l1.end_Point there is one path i.e. via l2.

Comment: From your description it sounds like `Point` should be a struct and not a class.

Answer (score 1):

Each line is an object with two pointers (potentially) pointing to two point objects, so if two lines reference the same point object and one goes out of scope, the point object does not, since the second line still contains a reference to it.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly nothing will happen to the Point objects in a separate instance of the Line class, provided they are in the class declaration like so:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Point a = new Point(0,0);
        Point b = new Point(2,2);
        Line line1 = new Line(a.X,a.Y, b.X, b.Y);
        Line line2 = new Line(a.X, a.Y, b.X, b.Y);          
    }
}

class Point
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
    public Point(int x1, int y1)
    {
        X = x1;
        Y = y1;
    }
}

class Line
{
    public Point StartPoint { get; set; }
    public Point EndPoint { get; set; }
    public Line(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
    {
        StartPoint = new Point(x1, y1);
        EndPoint = new Point(x2, y2);
    }
}
```

If line1 goes out of scope, you still have full access to the points in line2.

Comment: Thanks for making it more clear.
As line1 is out of scope so it is eligible for GC but the point object still have reference so will this line be GC'd at all ?

Comment: If you are talking about the point instances outside the Line class definition (points a and b), then will not go to GC just because line1 or or line2 did.  But it you are referring to StartPoint and Endpoint, then yes, they are GC'd when their specific line instance gets GC'd.

Answer (score 0):

The l1 reference will get GC'd but what it's pointing to would not as long as a reference still points to it--in your example, l2.

In other words, l1 and l2 are just references to an object (of type Point in this case) so as long as l1 and l2 really are pointing to the *same* object, there would be harsh results if the GC overlooked the fact that there is still a pointer being maintained to the object.